# how do i solve this type of error " Calling var(x) on a factor x is defunct" when making a standar coefficient for a logistic regression?

Tags: r, glm

Hi I was trying to use logistic regression in RSTUDIO about credit loan acceptance, I was doing the cleaning and of the data, but when I get to the last part of my code to make some predictions with the model and get the standard coefficients I get this error:

the variables in the logistic regression are:

`loan_status` (Y/N) Factor class and the rest of the independent variables there are factors and integers, in fact, I tried to convert all factor classes in numeric to solve the error like a saw in other question here but it didn't work, at the end only use as a factor un the dependant variable and the rest are integers or numeric type.

datasample:

```
structure(list(Gender = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2), Married = c(2, 
3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2), Dependents = c(2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 
5, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 2, 2, 4, 
2, 4), Education = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1), Self_Employed = c(2, 
2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1), ApplicantIncome = c(5849L, 4583L, 3000L, 
2583L, 6000L, 5417L, 2333L, 3036L, 4006L, 12841L, 3200L, 2500L, 
3073L, 1853L, 1299L, 4950L, 3596L, 3510L, 4887L, 2600L, 7660L, 
5955L, 2600L, 3365L, 3717L, 9560L, 2799L, 4226L, 1442L, 3750L
), CoapplicantIncome = c(0L, 1508L, 0L, 2358L, 0L, 4196L, 1516L, 
2504L, 1526L, 10968L, 700L, 1840L, 8106L, 2840L, 1086L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 3500L, 0L, 5625L, 1911L, 1917L, 2925L, 0L, 2253L, 1040L, 
0L, 2083L), LoanAmount = c(70L, 128L, 66L, 120L, 141L, 267L, 
95L, 158L, 168L, 349L, 70L, 109L, 200L, 114L, 17L, 125L, 100L, 
76L, 133L, 115L, 104L, 315L, 116L, 112L, 151L, 191L, 122L, 110L, 
35L, 120L), Loan_Amount_Term = c(360L, 360L, 360L, 360L, 360L, 
360L, 360L, 360L, 360L, 360L, 360L, 360L, 360L, 360L, 120L, 360L, 
240L, 360L, 360L, 360L, 360L, 360L, 360L, 360L, 360L, 360L, 360L, 
360L, 360L, 360L), Credit_History = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Property_Area = c(3L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L), Loan_Status = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("N", 
"Y"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")
```

Error when i run this line of code :

```
std.coff = data.frame(StandardCoeff = stz.ciff(spt_logit))

Error in var(if (is.vector(x) || is.factor(x)) x else as.double(x), na.rm = na.rm) 
Calling var(x) on a factor x is defunct.
Use something like 'all(duplicated(x)[-1L])' to test for a constant vector
```

the `str()` output for the database is:

```
str(subset)
'data.frame':   614 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ Gender           : num  3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ Married          : num  2 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ Dependents       : num  2 3 2 2 2 4 2 5 4 3 ...
 $ Education        : num  1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 ...
 $ Self_Employed    : num  2 2 3 2 2 3 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ ApplicantIncome  : int  5849 4583 3000 2583 6000 5417 2333 3036 4006 12841 ...
 $ CoapplicantIncome: int  0 1508 0 2358 0 4196 1516 2504 1526 10968 ...
 $ LoanAmount       : int  70 128 66 120 141 267 95 158 168 349 ...
 $ Loan_Amount_Term : int  360 360 360 360 360 360 360 360 360 360 ...
 $ Credit_History   : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 ...
 $ Property_Area    : int  3 1 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 2 ...
 $ Loan_Status      : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 1 ...
>
```

this is the complete code

---

```
data = read.csv("FILEPATH")
summary(data)

str(data)

hist(data$ApplicantIncome)
hist(data$CoapplicantIncome)
hist(data$LoanAmount)

is.na(data$LoanAmount)
colSums(is.na(data))
sum(is.na(data$LoanAmount))

library(mice)
md.pattern(data)

install.packages('VIM')

library(VIM)
aggr_plot <- aggr(data, col=c('navyblue','red'),numbers=TRUE, sortVars = TRUE, labels=names(data),cex.axis = 0.53, gap=0.5, cex.numbers=0.7, ylab=c("Histogram of missing data", "Pattern") )
marginplot(data[c(1,2)])

tempdata <- mice(data,m=5,maxit=50,meth ='pmm')
summary(tempdata)
completedData <- complete(tempdata, 1)

aggr_plot <- aggr(completedData, col=c('navyblue','red'),numbers=TRUE, sortVars = TRUE, labels=names(completedData),cex.axis = 0.53, gap=0.5, cex.numbers=0.7, ylab=c("Histogram of missing data", "Pattern") )
colSums(is.na(completedData))  
xtabs(~ Loan_Status+Credit_History, data = data)


#we are getting 75% of the data for training

datasort <- sort(sample(nrow(subset),nrow(subset)*.75))
train <- subset[datasort,]
test <- subset[-datasort,]

str(test)
str(train)
summary(completedData)

subset <- subset(completedData, select = -c(Loan_ID))
str(subset)

subset$Loan_Status <- as.factor(subset$Loan_Status)
subset$Property_Area <- as.integer(as.factor(subset$Property_Area))
subset$CoapplicantIncome <- as.integer(subset$CoapplicantIncome)
subset$Self_Employed <- as.numeric(as.factor(subset$Self_Employed))
subset$Education <- as.numeric(as.factor(subset$Education))
subset$Dependents <- as.numeric(as.factor(subset$Dependents))
subset$Married <- as.numeric(as.factor(subset$Married))
subset$Gender <- as.numeric(as.factor(subset$Gender))
str(subset)



logistic_regression <- glm(Loan_Status ~., data = train,family = "binomial", maxit = 100)
summary(logistic_regression)$coefficient

spt_logit = step(logistic_regression)

summary_step <- summary(spt_logit)$coefficient
summary_step

oddratios <- exp(coef(spt_logit))
summary_coef <- cbind(variable = row.names(summary_step),oddratios,summary_step)

row.names(summary_coef)=NULL

stz.ciff <- function(logitmodel){
  b<- summary(logitmodel)$coef[-1,1]
  sx<-sapply(logitmodel$model[-1],sd)
  beta<- (3^(1/2))/pi*sx*b
}

std.coff = data.frame(StandardCoeff = stz.ciff(spt_logit))
std.coff = cbind(variable = row.names(std.coff),std.coff)
row.names(std.coff)-NULL

final = merge(summary_coeff,std.coff,by="variable",all.x=TRUE)

pred = predict(spt_logit,test,type="response")
finaldata = cbind(test,pred)
```

Comment: Where exactly do you get the error? Please provide sample data (using `dput`) or at least the ouput of `str()`

Comment: When i run this line of code: std.coff = data.frame(StandardCoeff = stz.ciff(spt_logit))

Comment: i will update the `str()` on the question

Comment: If the error pops up there, we will need the data, not the structure to understand. Where does the function `stz.ciff` comes from?

Comment: @Claudio i already added the sample in the post and the function is to calculate the beta value

Comment: I can't replicate your error, using the models based on `completedData` the `stz.ciff` function works as expected. Probably the issue arises with variables that are included in the model by the `step` function when all cases are used. Try to run the function on the models that exclude one variable at a time to see if that's the case.